# SQLSRV Invalid parameter when converting DataTables from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sqlsrv

I am trying to convert this:
http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Into using SQLSRV, this is my code so far:

```
<?php

ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
define('IN_INDEX', 1);
require_once 'config.php';

    $aColumns = array( 'ID', 'CardNumber');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "ID";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "ActivityLog";


    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
    $sLimit = "OFFSET  ".$_GET['iDisplayStart']." ROWS 
                                FETCH NEXT ".$_GET['iDisplayLength']." ROWS ONLY "; 
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".addslashes( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT (*) OVER () AS ROW_COUNT ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = sqlsrv_query( $sQuery ) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = sqlsrv_query( $sQuery ) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
    $aResultFilterTotal = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = sqlsrv_query( $sQuery ) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
    $aResultTotal = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

When running this I get this error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14
>   [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.
>   [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) ) 1

This is how my connection is set up with SQL Server 2008:

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$DB_HOST;Database=$DB_DBNAME", $DB_USER, $DB_PWD);
```

I'm not too sure what the actual problem is, and I can't see a line number to check.

Edit: the HTML I'm using:

```
<table id="mainTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>CardNumber</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>CardNumber</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>


</table>

</div>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#mainTable').dataTable( {

            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/datatables.php"

                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

Comment: If you are connecting with PDO, you should not be using any of the `sqlsrv_*()` functions, and instead performing all your actions with the PDO object. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Alternatively, don't connect with PDO and instead [connect via `sqlsrv_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) but PDO  is probably a better choice because its prepared statement API (indeed its entire API) is consistent across any RDBMS you may use in the future.

Comment: If you use `sqlsrv_connect()` which would be a simpler path to to modify your code, functions like `sqlsrv_query()` expect the connection resource as the first parameter. That's the error reported - you passed a SQL string as its first parameter instead of the connection, but passing your PDO object wouldn't have worked either.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll try use `sqlsrv_connect()` and keep you updated.

Comment: Thanks, I got passed this error but now I'm prompted with another, `Incorrect syntax near 'ID'`

Comment: You'll have to echo out the SQL string being executed then to see if the syntax error can be spotted. Maybe missing whitespace, or maybe something else.

Comment: But I am thinking it is probably a missing comma between `ROW_COUNT` and the first column from the `implode()`, which is `ID`.

Comment: Thats' correct thanks, almost there now, I can see the data it just looks like the pagination is broken, I get this error in a javascript alert `DataTables warning: table id=mainTable - Requested unknown parameter '2' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`

Comment: I added `$sOrder = ""` and that error went away, now it's just trying to get the pages to show as it only shows 1 page with 10 rows but does say `Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries (filtered from 218,902 total entries)`

Answer (score 1):

In the end I fixed it with much help from [Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski)

Here is my final code:

```
<?php

$serverName = ""; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array( 'ID', 'TerminalNumber');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "ID";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "ActivityLog";


    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
    $sLimit = "OFFSET  ".$_GET['iDisplayStart']." ROWS 
                                FETCH NEXT ".$_GET['iDisplayLength']." ROWS ONLY "; 
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */

    $sOrder = ""; 
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".addslashes( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT (*) OVER () AS ROW_COUNT, ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";


    $rResult = sqlsrv_query($conn,  $sQuery ) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQueryRow = "
        SELECT ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
    ";
    $params = array();
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sQueryRow , $params, $options );

    $iFilteredTotal = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );


    //echo "TOTAL " . $iFilteredTotal;
    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = sqlsrv_query($conn,  $sQuery ) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
    $aResultTotal = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];




    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```